# NameError referencing class within a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following code:

```
class MyClass
    def method
        foo = MyClass.all
    end
end
```

which results in this error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant MyClass::MyClass)
```

It works fine if I change it to self.all, but the existing code works fine when I deploy to Heroku. It's only broken on my local system.

This is with a Rails 3.1.1 app and Ruby 1.9.2

Any ideas what's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do that. Assuming `all` is a class method and is not an instance method, do

```
class MyClass
    def method
        foo = self.class.all
    end
end
```

However, I think what's causing your problem is that in production, classes are cached. In development, they get reloaded on every request.

Comment: It's good practice to use `self.class` instead of an explicit class name anyway.  It's much better for inheritance especially since it will return the subclass.